# 2D array is initialized, but all items are null C#

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

So in Unity my this.tilesX and this.tilesY are both public variables that have a value in them. They are set in Unity's inspector. The debug.log after the initialization of the array reads out "10 x tiles 10 y tiles". So I know that both of those variables are initialized.

However, when I go to check if the this.tileLayer1 2D array's elements are null it returns the debug.log prints out "tile is null". I am completely lost. Below is the function that initializes the array as well as the constructor for my custom Tile class.

```
void Start () {

    this.tileLayer1 = new Tile[this.tilesY, this.tilesX];

    Debug.Log(tilesX + " x tiles " + tilesY + " y tiles");

    for (int y = 0; y < this.tileLayer1.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < this.tileLayer1.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            if (this.tileLayer1[x, y] == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("tile is null");
            }
        }
    }

    this.BuildMesh();
}
```

Here is the constructor that the new Tile code calls.

```
public Tile () {
    this.totalVerts = this.vertX * this.vertY;

    this.vertices = new Vector3[totalVerts];
    this.normals = new Vector3[totalVerts];
    this.uv = new Vector2[totalVerts];

    this.triangles = new int[6];
}
```

I do not think that the constructor has much to do with it, but who knows.

Comment: You are not initializing Array Items (Tiles). You are just initializing the array itself which will contain (At initializing time) null objects until you set values to them. Check `Dovydas Sopa`s answer below to see how to initialize array items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `this.tileLayer1 = new Tile[this.tilesY, this.tilesX];` only initialize array with `null` values.

You need to initialize each value

```
for (int y = 0; y < this.tileLayer1.GetLength(0); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < this.tileLayer1.GetLength(1); x++) {
        this.tileLayer1[x, y] = new Title();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not really use to using 2D arrays.

Comment: @Joshua Blevins It's actually the same as 1D arrays.

Comment: Didn't even think about that. I think I am just use to initializing arrays when in the declaration. Whereas the code I am writing cannot do that because the user sets the publics in the Unity GUI. Gotta break old habits of just droning when I write code and think my code through more.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize each element in array:

```
tileLayer1[0,0] = new Tile();
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless the array element type is a value type, the items will be always null after initialization and you must initialize the elements one by one.

If this is not the expected behavior and it makes sense to handle `Tile` as a value, then turn it into a value type (`struct`) so the array will be initialized by `default(Tile)` (bitwise zero) elements. That means `vertices`, `normals`, etc. will be null references in each element because no constructor is executed for the elements on array initialization.